# Regex pattern for obfuscated or compressed classes in jar file

Tags: java, regex, jar, obfuscation, reverse-engineering

I'm building a program that will take a jar file as input and determine the percentage of obfuscation applied to code. basically, I want to detect obfuscation at both package and class level using short identifiers. I want to use regex so that its language agnostic.

```
Le/e/e/e/a.class -> path obfuscation

Lcom/myapp/ui/ab.class -> class obfuscation

Lcom/myapp/ui/ab/aa.class -> package level
```

Comment: you cannot guarantee 0% false positives, because sometimes people can write code like this :D
and even harder is to get rid of false negatives — obfuscation may be more clever, use random words from dictionary for names, for example

Comment: but if you target a specific obfuscator then you can actually test your code on its output, until you get reasonable answers from your code

Comment: Likewise, I'm planning to build a whitelist dictionary for that purpose. For my ex above, "ui" can also be an obfuscated name or a shortform for GUI, if the obfuscator gets that far. However, I have my own algorithms for matching...but now I need the set of regex to flag out the suspect classes and packages.

Comment: And I want to ignore R.java for Android classes. Note the caps. Its easy to check against other classes for this. For a start, I think thats enough

Comment: I don't recommend using *only* regex — exceptions to simple rules are more easier done in a "real" programming language. I'd use regexes for initial matching and keep them simple... and after that discriminate special cases and maybe test some more complex rules

Comment: I'm a regex newbie. So how do I start?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html